# Sticky sidebar not sticking in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sticky

After way too much time agonizing over the breakage of a simple sticky sidebar component I've used without issue on numerous projects, I identified a partial solution that caused other issues.

This sidebar makes use of flexbox to keep the sidebar in place and treat a container div like the body of the page.

Unfortunately, it broke as soon as I started using it in Vue.js. I initially assumed it was because the element heights were not responding to dynamically populated content, but this is not the case.

The wrapper structure looks like so:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="wrapper">
         <div id="sidebar>
         </div>
         <div class="container">
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed !important;
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
#sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

NB: I did successfully cause the sidebar to *look* like it was sticking by setting the `body` height to 100%, but the actual links still scrolled, even though you could see the sidebar. Furthermore, this broke the layout properties of the Flatpickr datepicker being used on one of the most important pages in the site. Obviously, this is not a tenable solution, because a visible but interaction-less sidebar is useless, and I need my pages to actually work.

To be clear-- I chose to use `sticky` rather than `fixed` because I wanted to take advantage of flexbox to set the page content's container effectively next to the sidebar, rather than simply pushing it over using margin to keep it from being overlaid by the sidebar.

Here's a (messy, I apologize-- it's pulled out of a muuuuuuuch larger project) Codesandbox to show you the sidebar in context.

https://codesandbox.io/s/8897m88kl

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit more? What is the expected behavior? You say it broke, what do you mean? Does this codesandbox show the intended behavior, or the buggy behavior?

Comment: I would suggest to you to make use of [vue-affix](https://github.com/eddiemf/vue-affix), it is just one well written component that abstracts much of the work needed.

Comment: Sure! By "sticking," I mean that the sidebar should remain constantly visible in place and interactive as the page content scrolls. I say it broke because I've used this same sidebar code on plain html projects (ie no Vue or other JS-powered interface) with no issues. The sandbox shows the buggy behavior.

Comment: 1. Your Dispatch.vue component's wrapper has a `a-wrapper` class, but no associated styles. 2. Your Sidebar.vue component has a `wrapper` class (note the name mismatch) with associated styles, but the class is nowhere used. it's also scoped, so the class' styles won't apply when used outside of this component.

I would assume your problems are related to this. I also never saw a sticky element in a flexbox layout, unsure how this behaves ...

Comment: Ah, good catch! That's a remnant of changing `wrapper` to `a-wrapper` due to interference from Vuetify. The a-wrapper class is defined in the global css file and used in the Dispatch.vue file.

Comment: So i fixed that style issue and now I see a sidebar that's taking the full page height - but the main content seems to error out, and there's not enough content to scroll and try and understand what the buggy behaviour is ...

Comment: Don't I feel like a fool-- you have to go to "/example" to get the example content to display the scroll behavior. Somehow it didn't register in my brain that it wasn't doing so automatically.